# Generate Java 8 function using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, hbase

I try to modify anonymous Java classes to java 8 function interfaces. Below are the sample codes.

```
public static class PutFunction implements Function<String, Put> {

        @Override
        public Put call(String v) throws Exception {
            String[] cells = v.split(",");
            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(cells[0]));
            put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(cells[1]), Bytes.toBytes(cells[2]), Bytes.toBytes(cells[3]));

            return put;
        }
    }    


public static class DeleteFunction implements Function<byte[], Delete> {

            @Override
            public Delete call(byte[] v) throws Exception {
              return new Delete(v);
          }
  }
```

Then I generate Java 8 function codes which contain lambda expression from the above code.

```
private static Function<String, Put> hbasePutFunction() {
        return str -> str.split(",").map(cells -> new Put(Bytes.toBytes(cells[0])).addColumn(
                Bytes.toBytes(cells[1]), Bytes.toBytes(cells[2]), Bytes.toBytes(cells[3]));
    }


private static Function<byte[], Delete> hbaseDeleteFunction() {
        return v -> new Delete(v);
}
```

But I have some problems with these Java 8 function interfaces.

```
JavaHBaseContext hbaseContext = new JavaHBaseContext(jsc, conf);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(5);
list.add("1," + columnFamily + ",a,1");
list.add("2," + columnFamily + ",a,2");
list.add("3," + columnFamily + ",a,3");
list.add("4," + columnFamily + ",a,4");
list.add("5," + columnFamily + ",a,5");

JavaRDD<String> rdd = jsc.parallelize(list);

hbaseContext.bulkPut(rdd, TableName.valueOf(tableName), hbasePutFunction());
hbaseContext.bulkDelete(rdd, TableName.valueOf(tableName), hbaseDeleteFunction , 4);
```

I am a beginner at Java 8 lambda expression grammar.

### Update Part 1

`private static Function<String, Put> hbasePutFunction()` method throws the following exception,

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
     Expression
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
     Expression
```

And `hbaseContext.bulkDelete(rdd, TableName.valueOf(tableName), hbaseDeleteFunction , 4)` line throws the below exception

```
The method bulkDelete(JavaRDD<T>, TableName, Function<T,Delete>, Integer) in the type JavaHBaseContext is not applicable for the arguments (JavaRDD<String>, 
 TableName, Function<byte[],Delete>, int)
```

Any idea?

### Update Part 2

You are right! I modify some of codes to the below:

```
private static Function<String, Delete> hbaseDeleteFunction() {
        return str -> new Delete(Bytes.toBytes(str));
}
```

This statements throws no exception. Then how about the first exception? The following code throws the exception

```
private static Function<String, Put> hbasePutFunction() {
        return str -> str.split(",").map(cells -> new Put(Bytes.toBytes(cells[0])).addColumn(
                Bytes.toBytes(cells[1]), Bytes.toBytes(cells[2]), Bytes.toBytes(cells[3])));
    }
```

The error message seems like what you mentioned.

```
Cannot invoke map((<no type> cells) -> {}) on the array type String[]
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what problems you're having.

Comment: Btw, you can replace `v -> new Delete(v)` with `Delete::new`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Pls, check the **== Update Part ==** .

Comment: From the second error, it looks like there's a conflict about type `T`. In the first parameter it's `String`, but in the third it's `byte[]`.

Comment: Would you check the 2nd **==Update Part 2==**, pls.

Comment: You can't call `map()` on an array.